# A variant of Knuth shuffle

Tags: algorithm, probability, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

This is a very hard but interesting probability question related to Knuth/Fisher-Yates shuffle.

When looping for each element, the swap is performed for the current element with any random element from the whole array (not within the elements left), then what is the probabilty of the original i<sup>th</sup> element ending up at the j<sup>th</sup> position?

Comment: This question is about "a specific algorithm", which is in the ToR for this site. It's commonly believed that a naïve shuffle is only "slightly off", and it is entirely appropriate to seek quantification of the bias.

Comment: @rici I'm adding a note here that the common belief is wrong.  For `n=10` the pattern `2 3 4 5 1 7 8 9 10 6` is more than 50 times as likely to come up than the pattern `10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.  This is not a small bias at all!

Answer (score 5):

The Knuth shuffle is as follows (in Python, but it could be pseudocode)

```
for i in range(len(v)):
  swap(v, i, randrange(i, len(v))
```

The naïve shuffle is very similar, but it is *not* the Knuth shuffle:

```
for i in range(len(v)):
  swap(v, i, randrange(0, len(v))
```

The Knuth shuffle produces uniformly-distributed permutations. The naïve shuffle can be proven not to, because there are *n*<sup>*n*</sup> possible sequences of random numbers, each of which has an equal probability, and *n*! possible permutations, which is not a factor of *n*<sup>*n*</sup>. (The Knuth shuffle, on the other hand, involves precisely *n*! possible random number sequences, each of which can be proven to produce a unique permutation.)

The above proof does not indicate whether or not the individual permutation positions in the naïve shuffle are uniformly distributed. It is possible for a non-uniform distribution of permutations to nonetheless produce a uniform distribution of permutation elements: for example, if all permutations other than rotations have probability 0, and rotations have equal probability, then the permutation elements will be uniformly distributed. (That would be an even worse shuffle than the naïve shuffle.)

As it turns out, the naïve shuffle does *not* produce uniformly distributed element positions. There are two points of regularity: the final position of the first element in the vector is uniformly distributed, as is are the elements which end up in the final position.

The most likely final position of element *i* (*i*≠0) is the position *i*−1.

Here's a table of transition probabilities for *n*=8, computed as a product of transition matrices:

```
from/to     0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
  0      .125    .125    .125    .125    .125    .125    .125    .125
  1      .158    .116    .117    .118    .119    .121    .123    .125
  2      .144    .151    .110    .112    .115    .118    .121    .125
  3      .132    .139    .147    .107    .111    .115    .119    .125
  4      .122    .129    .137    .146    .107    .112    .118    .125
  5      .113    .120    .128    .137    .147    .110    .117    .125
  6      .105    .112    .120    .129    .139    .151    .116    .125
  7      .098    .105    .113    .122    .132    .144    .158    .125
```

It's possible to derive a closed-form for **P**<sub>*n*</sub>(*i*, *j*) -- the probability that element *i* in a vector of *n* elements will be shuffled to position *j*.

In the algorithm, the *swap* at iteration *i* involves the element *v*<sub>*i*</sub> and some other element *v*<sub>*j*</sub>. (It's possible that *i*=*j*.) Although *swap* is a symmetric operation, it's useful to distinguish the two elements; we'll call this an *out swap* of the element *v*<sub>*i*</sub> and an *in swap* of *v*<sub>*j*</sub>

Note that after an *in swap* of element *k*, *k* can no longer be *out swapped*, because all the following *out swaps* are at positions following the new position of *k*. So if *k* is ever *out swapped*, it must be *out swapped* at iteration *k*; in other words, only the first swap involving an element can be at *out swap*.

Now, at a any iteration of the shuffle, the final destinations of the element about to be *out swapped* are uniformly distributed. (The probability of the final destination being *j* is the sum over all *i* of the probability of the next position being *i* times the probability that the final destination of the next position *i* being *j*. Since the next positions are uniformly distributed, the multiplier can be factored out, and the remaining sum is 1 since *j* must come from some *i*.)

Also, for an element which is never *out swapped*, its final destination is the iteration at which its last *in swap* occurred. (It's not possible for an element to be neither *out swapped* nor *in swapped*. If no *in swap* occurs before the element is in the *out swap* position, it will be *out swapped*.)

With all that, we can derive the formula for the transition function.

First, the probability that element *k* will be *out swapped* is precisely the probability that it is not *in swapped* in any of the iterations prior to *k*, which is (*n*-1)<sup>*k*</sup>/*n*<sup>*k*</sup>. Among the shuffles in which *k* is *out swapped*, the final destination is uniformly distributed, so this contributes (*n*−1)<sup>*k*</sup>/*n*<sup>*k*+1</sup> to every transition probability **P**<sub>*n*</sub>(*k*, *j*).

Now let's consider the cases in which the last *in swap* is at iteration *j* (and hence to position *j*). At every iteration, a given element will be *in swapped* with probability 1/*n*. Consequently, the probability that the last *in swap* is at iteration *j* is the probability that no swap occurs after *j* times the probability that the swap occurs at iteration *j*, which is (*n*−1)<sup>*n−j−1*</sup>/*n*<sup>*n−j*</sup>.

If *j*<*k*, then *k* cannot be *out swapped*, but if *j*≥*k*, we need to only count the cases where there was a swap prior to iteration *k*. This leads to the following definition:

**P**<sub>*n*</sub>(*k*, *j*) = (*n*−1)<sup>*k*</sup>/*n*<sup>*k*+1</sup> + (1−**O**<sub>*n*</sub>(*k*, *j*))×(*n*−1)<sup>*n-j-1*</sup>/*n*<sup>*n−j*</sup>

where

**O**<sub>*n*</sub>(*k*, *j*) = 0 if *j*<*k*, and otherwise (*n*−1)<sup>*k*</sup>/*n*<sup>*k*</sup>

Comment: I think this explanation can be simplified, and there might be some simplification to the formulas (although Wolfram didn't help me much). I'll look at it again tomorrow, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) compares the algorithm you mention with Knuth's, showing why Knuth's is better.

**Note: the below might be wrong, see the comments.**

I'm not aware of an easy way to compute the probability you ask about and I can't seem to find any simple explanation either, but the idea is that your algorithm (usually referred to as the naive shuffle algorithm) considers `n^n` permutations of the array instead of `n!`. This is because element `i` can end up at each of `n` positions at step `i`. Since you have `n` possibilities at each step and `n` steps, that adds up to `n^n`. Since `n^n` is not always divisible by `n!` it follows that not all permutations have the same probability, which is why the algorithm is considered a bad shuffle.

Since not all permutations have the same probability, it follows that the probability you ask about is different for different values of `i` and `j`, but I'm not aware of a formula that computes it.

Comment: It would in theory be possible for the permutations to be non-uniformly distributed, while the individual element locations are still uniformly distributed. For example, suppose that the only permutations produced by an algorithm are rotations. If the rotations are uniformly distributed, then so are the element locations. The difference is that the element locations are not *independently* uniformly distributed. (I believe that the naive algorithm referred to in the OP doesn't distribute either permutations or element positions uniformly, but I don't know for sure either.)

Comment: @rici - yes, but if that were the case here, wouldn't the naive shuffle work well in practice?

Comment: Surely the point of shuffling is to shuffle. Suppose you are playing some card game with a shuffler who provides you with the correct probability of receiving the Ace of Spades and also the correct probability of receiving the King of Spades. However, you always either receive both or neither. Is that "working well in practice?" I think not.

Comment: OK, I worked out a closed form, and the probabilities are definitely not uniform (except at the margin). Answer provided in case you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

In a proper Knuth shuffle, you loop over `i` elements choosing one of 52 to swap with element 1, then one of 51 remaining to swap with element 2, one of of 50 remaining to swap with element 3, etc. Once an element has been placed into the growing set 1,2,3... it will never move again. So the odds of element `i` ending up in position 1 is exactly 1/52--it can only happen on the first loop. The odds of it ending up in cell 2 are the odds of it not being in cell 1 (51/52) times the odds of it being chosen on the second pass (1/51). The 51s cancel, leaving 1/52. Likewise, the chance of element `i` ending up in position 3 is 51/52 * 50/51 * 1/50, again 1/52. So every element has an equal chance to end up in each cell.

In your shuffle, already-placed elements may be chosen again for later switching, which makes calculating the odds very difficult.